# How to print life of a thread in seconds?

Tags: c, pthreads

I need to print life of a thread after x seconds, I can delay it by `sleep()` function but I'm not sure how to print life of thread.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <time.h>

   void *thread_life(void *arg)
   {

    while(1) 
     {
          printf("\n"); //print time 
          sleep(3);
     }


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Print life of thread"?

Comment: lifetime of a thread, its total life from its creation to end

Comment: Time since when, in what? Since creation? In seconds?

Comment: yes in seconds.

Comment: as it's written now the thread will never end. You can [`clock_gettime`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) right before/after creation, then again right before/after termination, and compare the times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). Understand that there are several notions of time (see [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)): elapsed time, monotonic time,  thread cpu time, process cpu time.

To get the current date and time (as a string), use [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html), [localtime_r(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime_r.3.html), [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html).

If you need to wait for some time, do an idle wait with [pause(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pause.2.html), [nanosleep(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html), [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html).

BTW, don't forget that `printf` (more precisely `stdout`) is buffered (usually line-buffered). See [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html), [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html).

Read also some [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) (notably to understand mutexes, condition variables, broadcasts, ...). See also [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) and [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). Remember that a thread needs to be joined ([pthread_join(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html)) or detached ([pthread_detach(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_detach.3.html)).